# RMI programming example

Tags: java, rmi

I've to develop an application running RMI between a server and a client. 
Initially, the server multicasts "alive" messages and clients respond with their current status(IP and usage statistics).
When a button is pressed on the server's UI, the operation should be executed on the specific client after which the client returns status of operation(implemented by RMI)

1.Currently, I'm sending out multicast alive messages-using isReachable(subnet) and getting IP's of all active clients. However without sockets, I'm unable to get the client's stats in return. Any suggestions?

2.After step 1, how do I execute the RMI call so that the operation is executed on the specific client and status returned?

Since this is an initial version of the application, I'm currently not using programs like Jini. Just want to set up a basic version up and running.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote out a whole program using 
1. [For network discovery](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html) 
2. used [RMI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html) with serialization to transfer objects